# entity not getting updated on the fly

Tags: .net, wpf

I am making an application using wpf in the .NET framework (using visual studio). I have an entity "User", the entity constitutes of various properties :
1. Name varchar
2. IsCanRead
3. IsCanWrite

the 2nd and the 3rd properties control whether a user can read or write or both. These are bound to check boxes. According to the checkboxes checked 3 dropdowns are displayed in the other screen 
1. Dropdown one consists of people who can read
2. dropdown 2 consists of people who can write
3 Third dropdown gives the names of those who can do both

now whenever I change any property for the entity I have to reload the screen to see the changes. Can anyone please help me , and tell me how I can I ensure that the user doesn't need to reload the screen? and the changes are reflected immediately?

Below is the xaml code

```
     <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="Name">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
     </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
     <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <behavior:AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$" MaxLength="50"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Can Read?" SortMemberPath="IsCanRead">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCanRead}" IsEnabled="False" />
</DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCanRead, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

             <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Can Write?" SortMemberPath="IsCanWrite">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCanWrite}" IsEnabled="False" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCanWrite, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: IsCanRead and IsCanWrite take Boolean values because they are bound to check boxes

Comment: Show the actual class and the actual bindings as found in Xaml, keeping it as concise but not filled with unnecessary info such as `Width` parameters in  Xaml.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to reload the screen to see the changes

Reloading of the whole object suggest that either the class which holds the values does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or that the bindings in Xaml could be set the `Mode` to `TwoWay` to facility any changes be kept in sync either front to back or visa versa.

Example of the `INotifyProperty` usage required

```
private bool _IsCanRead;

public bool IsCanRead
{
    get { return _IsCanRead; }
    set { _IsCanRead= value; OnPropertyChanged("IsCanRead"); }
}
```

Example of the `TwoWay` mode binding:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCanRead,
                              Mode=TwoWay
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: If I change the name of the user, it is being reflected in the other screen on the fly, but this is not working for the others.

Comment: @Manika Please show your Xaml code which binds with the class and show the Xaml binding to so we can try to reproduce. :-)

Comment: @Manika What is the class which is being bound to? Can you create an example in a side project in WPF which doesn't have all the chatter from the main project, then show it here so we can reproduce it on our ends? Thanks.